# Trouble connecting bot to Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, discord, discord.py

I've recently decided that I wanted to start learning more about real-world Python and the applications associated therewith. As a way to do this, I tried to code a simple Discord bot. However, I'm running into a different problem than any other that I've seen on any platform — including this one: `can't find '__main__' module in 'bot'`. I get this error when I run `python bot` in the Command Prompt. Now, I assume that I should indeed be running `python bot` instead of `python bot.py` since .py only denotes that bot is a Python file. I assumed this because when I run `python bot.py`, I get the following message: `python: can't open file 'bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Here's bot.py:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user(), "has connected to Discord!")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Additionally, when I run bot.py in the Python shell, I receive the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

And, I'm not sure where (or even if) this was addressed in the code, but here's .env.txt:

```
#.env
DISCORD_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Ok, I think that covers everything. If anyone needs clarification for any section(s) of this, I would be happy to provide it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it output if you ``print(TOKEN)``?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the path of your .env file inside `load_dotenv`. Because at the moment your `TOKEN` is returning `None`

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("myenvfile.env") # <-- you can enter your .env file like so
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user(), "has connected to Discord!")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

.env

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```